# fail to load external js files in angular4 components

Tags: angular

I have angular 4 applicaiton in which i want to integrate form wizard. I have downloaded form wizard from a link and it has 3 .js files which i have to load in my component. I have tried various methods but still .js files are not loading. 
 I have tried to in this way in my register.component.ts

```
import '../../assets/js/jquery.bootstrap.js';
import '../../assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js';
import '../../assets/js/material-bootstrap-wizard.js';
```

also include in my angular-cli.json file in this way

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "./src/assets/js/jquery.bootstrap.js",
    "./src/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "./src/assets/js/material-bootstrap-wizard.js"
  ]
```

But from both methods files are not loading. 
How can i load these external .js files into my angular component.?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: getting 2,3 erros likes this
1)
isotope not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().isotope("layout")
2)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>

Comment: @DheerajKumar  guide me about how can i load external js files in my component.

Comment: Plz add your code from component and html